# Divide a SQL file into smaller files and save each of them as a CSV/Excel/TXT file dynamically

Tags: sql, hana

So, I'm working on a SAP HANA database that has 10 million records in one table and there are 'n' number of tables in the db. The constraints that I'm facing are:

1. I do not have write access to the db.
2. The maximum RAM in the system is 6 GB.

Now, I need to extract the data from this table and save it as a csv or txt or excel file. I tried `Select * from query`. Using this the machine extracts ~700k records before showing an out of memory exception.

I've tried using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in SAP HANA and it works perfectly, but it takes around ~30 mins for the machine to process ~500k records. So, going by this route will be very time consuming.

So, I wanted to known if there is anyway by which I can automate the process of selecting 500k records using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` and save each such sub-file containing 500k records automatically into as a csv/txt file on the system, so that I can run this query and leave the system overnight to extract data.

Comment: you can use export command to export all data in csv. Refermention link [link] (https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20da0bec751910148e69c9668ea3ccb8.html)

Comment: With a maximum RAM of 6 GB HANA would not be able to run. This looks like a typo.

Comment: @SomendraKanaujia I do not have the required privileges to export the data using that command.

Comment: @LarsBr. Well these are the specs of the VM that I have to use to extract the data where SAP HANA has been installed.

Comment: There never had been a version of HANA that was supported to run under 12 GB of RAM. Even the HANA Express Edition requires about that at the absolute minimum. Are you sure this is GB and not TB?

Comment: @LarsBr. yup I'm 100% sure this GB.

Comment: In that case, this thing runs well below the required memory - not surprised about the bad performance. Using the `EXPORT` command mentioned by Somendra is your best bet here to achieve your goal.

Comment: @LarsBr. Sure, I tried that but I don't have the privileges to Export data. So, I think I'll continue using LIMIT and OFFSET to view data and then export the results.

Comment: Honestly, this sounds as if the owner of the system just doesn't want to you take all the data...